# vue2-datepicker can not disable future dates

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

```
**Template **

<date-picker
            :disabled="form.type != 1"
            input-class="form-control"
            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
            range
            v-model="form.date"
            valueType="format"
            :not-after="disabledAfter">
</date-picker>
```

**Scripts** Vue2-Datepicker version 3.3.0

```
data(){
    return{
         disabledAfter: new Date(2020, 4, 30),
    }
}
```

Can not disable future dates. Is it about version?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable future dates, just add:

```
:disabled-date="(date) => date >= new Date()"
```

Comment: @asalgan Are you sure your date state is put in properly? I can assure you, this works.

Comment: yes it looks like this 
```
<date-picker
      :input-name="name"
      v-model="tempValue"
      lang="en"
      :disabled-date="(date) => date >= new Date()"
      @input="onInput"
    >
```
and the `:disabled-date` doesn't do anything, all future dates are not disabled.

Comment: That is because you're inserting the wrong value. If your value is "tempValue", it should be `:disabled-date="(tempValue) => tempValue >= new Date()`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
:allowed-dates="(date) => date <= new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable future dates try to use [functional-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-functional-calendar) , in this package you can set Prop `:disabledDates` with type array , or `:limits` with type [Object, Boolean] like this :

```
<functional-calendar 
    :value="valcalendarData" 
    :limits='limit' 
    ref="Calendar"
    v-model="calendarData" 
    :isMultipleDatePicker='true'>
</functional-calendar>
```

In script

```
data(){
    return{
         limit:{min: '8/02/2020', max: '24/2/2020'},
    }
}
```

Or , `disabled-date` Prop in [vue2-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-datepicker) to specify the date that cannot be selected

Answer (score 0):

Use prop called **disabled-date**, in this prop specify the date that cannot be selected.
An example here, this will disable yesterday and all the previous dates

```
<date-picker 
    placeholder="Survey Period" 
    style="width: 100%;" 
    class="" 
    v-model="time3" 
    range
    @change="period" 
    :disabled-date="(date) => date <= new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))">
</date-picker>
```